# GHDL -fsynopsys and -fexplicit options

Tags: vhdl, ieee, ghdl

I wrote the code using ieee.std_logic_unsigned package and now I have problem compiling it. Is there a way to use options --fsynopsys and -fexplicit at the same time since I need them to get rid of errors? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys -fexplicit filename.vhd
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use std_logic_unsigned for new code. Use numeric_std_unsigned instead. That is the real IEEE package. See [When to use VHDL library std_logic_unsigned and numeric_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45704135/4966843)